# Is it possible to assign all schemas to a single login without specifying?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work with a DB where schemas get added and removed regularly, and preferably I would be able to assign all schemas to a single user with a script.

but as far as I can see, I always have to specify the schema like

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::schema_name TO myUser;
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: `CREATE SCHEMA` has an optional `AUTHORIZATION` clause -- consider just always passing that, assuming schema creation is done centrally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'',
  @base nvarchar(max) = N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::$s$ TO myUser;';

SELECT @sql += REPLACE(@base, N'$s$', QUOTENAME(name))
  FROM sys.schemas;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql;
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket, but still, the += method didn't work for me. I used it like this and then it works, thanks. `SELECT REPLACE(N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::$s$ TO user;', N'$s$', name) FROM sys.schemas;`

Comment: @DerekBushiko Should be fixed now. Sorry this isn't something you can test on db<>fiddle because we can't create schemas there.

Comment: Ah, so the issue was not Initializing @sql, I feel stupid for not noticing. Thanks again.